# Unable to Utilize Application.Select.Find in a Word 2013 VSTO Plug-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, visual-studio-2015, ms-office, vsto

I'm a rank novice at C#, and am currently using Visual Studio 2015 to try and create a Ribbon-based VSTO Plug-in for Word 2013 that accomplishes the following tasks upon a button click:

- Takes input from the user in a text box.
- Finds a set series of characters ("xxxxx") and uses the previous user input to replace the set throughout the document.
- Saves the document as a PDF.

I am currently able to perform the **first** and **last** tasks fine. Ironically enough, I have used code directly from the [MSDN article on Find & Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-11), but keep encountering an error preventing my build. I have tried a number of solutions, including replacing `Application.Selection.Find` with `Word.Selection.Find`, and `WordApp.Selection.Find`, but to no avail.

My exact error is as follows: "
Error   CS0117  'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Selection'"

I feel so close to victory here it's driving me batty. I've posted my full code below.

Thank you very much in advance for any help and/or insight provided!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;

namespace RestRef_Automator_Test
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private bool flag;

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get, Find, & Replace RID
            int myRID = 0;
            string myString = myRID.ToString();

            flag = int.TryParse(RID.Text, out myRID);
            if (flag == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in a number.", "Input Error");
                return;
            }

            Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Text = "xxxxx";
            findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Replacement.Text = myString;

            object replaceALL = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            object missing = null;
            findObject.Execute(
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref replaceALL, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            //Save as PDF w/ applicable name.
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "*";
            dlg.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            dlg.ValidateNames = true;
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            { Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(dlg.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport: true); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is still relevant. But I remember getting a CS0117 at some point. [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821175) page then helped me resolve it.

Comment: @NickOtten, thank you for this! Much appreciated. Unfortunately, due to my rather low skill level, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how it would be implemented in the code above. If you have the time, would you mind me asking for an example using the above? If not, it's no problem at all! Thank you again!

Comment: I was making the example when I noticed something different, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up on the comments below the original question, When looking over the code to make the example I noticed you where using the wrong application object. Instead of asking Ms Word to find your selection you where asking it to your C# application.

I don't have Ms Word installed on my computer but out of memory I'd say you should change

```
Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
```

to

```
var app = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Word.Find findObject = app.Selection.Find;
```

Keep in mind that this solution expects that Ms Word is up and running. If word is not running it would result in a exception.

Comment: You, sir, are a brain-saver. Thank you so much! Just to note, while this has successfully allowed me to build my add-in, I am unfortunately unable to actually replace text at this stage. This one's on me though, and many thanks to you!

Comment: @NickDonegan Glad I could help, as for your follow up problem: Check if you are connected to the right word instance (check task manager and make sure only 1 WORD.EXE is in the process list).

Answer (score 1):

Nick's analysis is correct, but the suggested solution is not optimal for a VSTO add-in.

Since this is a VSTO add-in, using `GetObject` to get the instance of the Word.Application is *not* the correct approach. The Word.Application is available directly through any VSTO add-in, since the add-in is running in-process with the Word.Application.

In the `ThisAddIn.cs` class, usually in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event:

```
Word.Application wdApp = this.Application;
```

If you want/need to access it from a different class, then either declare the Word.Application object as a class member and assign it in `ThisAddIn_Startup`

OR access it through the `Globals` object, which gives your code access to all VSTO objects across all classes:

```
Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've edited my code with your suggestion, and everything seems much cleaner now. I also finally got the replace working, so you guys are officially awesome!

Comment: You're welcome @NickDonegan :-) Since you're new to the site: The "right" way to thank people for useful information is to upvote (the up-arrow next to the contribution). With the checkmark next to "the" Answer. You can upvote as many contributions as you want; there can be only one "Answer".

Comment: Absolutely, and thank you for letting me know! I've upvoted both you and @NickOtten, but it looks like my rep isn't high enough to have a visible impact just yet. My thanks are still real, though!